# how to delete Oauth access token in Netsuite?

Tags: oauth, netsuite

I have run more times to get oauth access token for testing. I crossed over the limit. Now i tried to delete access token in any one way GUI or code. I got the following message.

```
This user has exceeded the number of active access tokens this role.
```

After setting inactive , I can get access token again. But How to delete those active and inactive tokens in GUI mode?

Setup -> User / Roles -> Access Tokens -> New Access Token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Setup -> User / Roles -> Access Tokens (Click on the Access Tokens
>   link itself)
>
> 2) You will list of users and their tokens, click edit link
>
> 3) Click Revoke button

Comment: ( Revoke )  That word , i have fallen on Revoke. You helped me more times . Thanks Prasun.

Comment: Is there any possiblity to delete access token by code?

Comment: not that I am aware of, probably netsuite prefers security configurations from UI